# Inner product of two complex vectors?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Given $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$real matrix. If $\langle x,y\rangle =y^{*}x$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb C^{n \times 1}$, can someone help me find the relationship between the following two expressions:

$\frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|}{||x||\cdot||y||}$ (1)

$\frac{|\langle Ax,Ay\rangle|}{||Ax||\cdot||Ay||}$ (2)

is there any approximation or bound which can link (1) and (2)?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz?

Comment: thanks. that's true that both (1) and (2) are bounded by 0 and 1. I actully want to show that minimizing (1) also somehow minimizes (2)? or can (2) be written as a function of (1) using some approximation?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizing" (1) and (2)?  Do you mean to show that, for example, if (2) is equal to zero, then (1) is also is equal to zero?  That certainly isn't the case in general

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am actually dealing with a quantization problem. Given $x$, I want to choose the $y$, which minimizes (1), from a set of random vectors (a codebook). So here equation (1) is the selection criterion. However, equation (2) is the function I actually need to minimize. Consider extreme cases when $x, y$ are orthogonal, equation (1)=equation (2)=0. if $x, y$ are collinear, then equation (1)=equation (2)=1.
But I also want to find the relationship between (1) and (2) for other intermiate values.